# Uploading files using Uplodify works sometime and sometime it does not

Tags: php, file-upload, uploadify

I installed Uploadify UI on my site so I can allow user to upload files to my site. It is working now but the problem is that it uploads files sometimes and sometimes it does not. So I can upload an png file and it will work no problems. but when I upload excel file it will allow some to be uploaded and some it work allow it.

I am not sure what can I check to see what is causing the issue.

I have tried to turn the debuger on 'debug' : true but that did not give me any clues. I also looked at my php logs and there was no error/warnings there.

I am not sure what else I can check but I will apreshiate any type of help with this.

Here is my javascript code to set it up

```
<?php $timestamp = time();?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'formData'     : {
                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                'token'     : '<?php echo md5($timestamp);?>',
                'upload_path': 'ticketing_center/',
                'allowed_extentions': 'jpg,jpeg,gif,PNG,JPG,png,JPEG, jpeg,zip,rar,doc,docx,cvs,xls,xlsx,txt'
            },
            'auto' : true,
            'debug' : true,
            'swf'      : '../../includes/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : '../../includes/uploadify.php',
            'fileSizeLimit' : '50MB',
            'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.JPG; *.png; *.PNG; *.JPEG; *.jpeg; *.zip; *.rar; *.doc; *.docx; *.cvs; *.xls; *.xlsx; *.txt;',
            'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                if(data != 'INVALID'){
                    $('#attached_files').append('<input type="hidden" name="attachments[]" value="'+ $.trim(data) +'" />');
                } else {
                    alert('Invalid File Type');
                }
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

the following is my PHP script

```
<?php
    $targetFolder = '';
    $verifyToken = '100';
    $actualToken = '';
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');

    if(isset($_POST['upload_path'])){
        $targetFolder = $_POST['upload_path'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['timestamp'])){
        $verifyToken = md5($_POST['timestamp']);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['token'])){
    $actualToken = $_POST['token'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['allowed_extentions'])){

        $types = explode(',', $_POST['allowed_extentions']);

        if(count($types) > 0 ){
            $fileTypes = $types;
        }
    }


    if (!empty($_FILES) && $actualToken == $verifyToken) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath =  ROOT_FIXED . UPLOAD_DIR . $targetFolder;   //$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
        $targetPath = str_replace( "//", "/", $targetPath);
        $new_filename = USER_ID . '_' . time() . '_' . str_replace(" ", "_", $_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
        $targetFile = $targetPath . $new_filename;

        // Validate the file type
        //$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
        $fileParts = pathinfo($new_filename);  //str_replace(" ", "_", $_FILES['Filedata']['name'])

        if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
            echo trim($new_filename);
        } else {
            echo 'INVALID';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: What exactly happens when you upload a file and it fails? Does it hang, do you get a white screen, etc..?

Comment: No it acts like it has been uploaded. The flash show it has need completed. No errors of any kind and it finish but the files does not get moved to the server. I wish I got an error that would give me something to start

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why people vote your questions down without a comment that will help you understand why. but any way to help other that will run into the same issue. Here is the solution

the configuration in my php.ini file were set to a low limites. Max upload file was set to 2M

go to php.ini and find the

- upload_max_filesize - set to 50M
- post_max_size - set to 50M
- max_execution_time - set to 120
- max_input_time - set to 50

Restart our apache and now you should be able to upload files up to 50MB in size